# PID created with system()

Tags: process, nice

i'm new in ubuntu. 
I'm creating a programm with opens 2/4/8 new process in separate terminals.
Using system().
How can i get PID of them, or change nice value, using another terminal?

Comment: Don't use system then. Fork and then exec.

Comment: Cant find info on, how to open qt c++ prog in new process with those commands.

Comment: @Max: FYI [`fork(2)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man2/fork.2.html) and [`exec(3)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man3/exec.3.html), and [tutorials on](https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/416/notes/c-tutorials/forkexec.html) [their usage](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/icsrts/Tutorials/fork_exec/). [`system(3)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man3/system.3.html) isn't that portable and can be a security risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally [`pidof(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/pidof.8.html) and in more complicated cases [`pgrep(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/pgrep.1.html) are excellent tools to find the ID of some processes.

If you want to find all children of a particular process, you need to dig through the `/proc` file system yourself. Let's assume you're looking for the children of process 2345:

```sh
for PROCSTAT in /proc/[0-9]*/stat; do
    read -r PID PROCNAME STATUS PPID TAIL < $PROCSTAT
    if [ $PPID -eq 2345 ]; then
        echo $PID
    fi
done
```

If you choose to use

```c
system("foobar");
```

instead of

```c
if (fork() == 0) {
    execlp("foobar", "foobar", NULL);
}
```

it'll actually spawn two processes: `/bin/sh` as a direct child and `foobar` as a grandchild.